# Installing Ubuntu on a USB stick from live CD session

Tags: installation, usb, live-cd, kvm-virtualization

I'm going by the instructions here:
[How do I install Ubuntu to a USB key? (without using Startup Disk Creator)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key)

Everything is ok except I keep getting the error:

```
open /dev/kvm: no such file or directory
could not initialize kvm, will disable kvm support
failed to find rom file etc. etc.
```

Then the kvm window opens but it is black and says remove disks or other media and press any key to restart.

I am booted up in a live CD session and trying to install on a usb stick.

Comment: I don't know how I got it working but I now have a full install on my USB stick. I　think that it may have had something to do with how I preformatted the stick. STAY AWAY FROM FAT32!!! Ext3 is the way to go. If you format FAT32 then you will get stuck with a 4gig partition limit. I　think I　formatted the disk with gparted under the install cd somehow and then was able to install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please try to make the USB key bootable using UNetbootin and ISO from Ubuntu.com?

Please keep me informed.